# Ignore N/A values in td beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to remove N/A values in td of same class

```
  <td align="left" class="category"> N/A</td>
<td align="left" class="title"> <a href="article-feb-0243.html">Wall Street cool to eBay's profit</a></td>
<td align="left" class="category"> technology</td>
<td align="left" class="title"> <a href="article-feb-2017.html">Warnings about junk mail deluge</a></td>
<td align="left" class="category"> technology</td>
<td align="left" class="title"> <a href="article-feb-2660.html">Web radio takes Spanish rap global</a></td>
<td align="left" class="category"> sport</td>
```

I want to scrape both category and title but in category want to ignore N/A values

```
for td in parsed_html.body.findAll('td',{"class":lambda class_: class_ in ("category","title")}):
                print(td)
                category=td.parent.find("td",attrs={"class":"category"}).text

                if(not td.parent.find("i")):
                    url=td.parent.find("a")["href"]
```

I have tried matching string to N/A but it dint work

Comment: perhaps try stripping the text since the ` N/A` seems to have a space in front of it.

Comment: You used `td.parent.find` in your try but where is the relevant portion of that parent. It's hard to provide you with any solution out of this minimal html elements. Try adding a chunk of containers. Thanks.

Comment: I provided now more td's as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't have to use custom function to match multiple classes. You can pass the different classes as a list.

Second, there are two ways you can go about in getting what you want. You can simply check if the text contains `N/A` while iterating over all the `<td>` tags and skip the tag if it is present.

```
html = '''
<td align="left" class="category"> N/A</td>
<td align="left" class="title"> <a href="article-feb-0243.html">Wall Street cool to eBay's profit</a></td>
<td align="left" class="category"> technology</td>
<td align="left" class="title"> <a href="article-feb-2017.html">Warnings about junk mail deluge</a></td>
<td align="left" class="category"> technology</td>
<td align="left" class="title"> <a href="article-feb-2660.html">Web radio takes Spanish rap global</a></td>
<td align="left" class="category"> sport</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for td in soup.find_all('td', class_=['category', 'title']):
    if 'N/A' in td.text:
        continue
    print(td)
```

Output:

```
<td align="left" class="title"> <a href="article-feb-0243.html">Wall Street cool to eBay's profit</a></td>
<td align="left" class="category"> technology</td>
<td align="left" class="title"> <a href="article-feb-2017.html">Warnings about junk mail deluge</a></td>
<td align="left" class="category"> technology</td>
<td align="left" class="title"> <a href="article-feb-2660.html">Web radio takes Spanish rap global</a></td>
<td align="left" class="category"> sport</td>
```

---

You could also do this using a custom function.

```
for td in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'td' and tag['class'][0] in ('category', 'title') and 'N/A' not in tag.text):
    print(td)
```